# Are Quest libraries(Quest authentication services) thread safe?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

While using the api `getpwnam_r()` to retrieve userinfo, this api calls quest library (`libvas.so.2`) internally. In multi-threaded environment, my program dumps core. Are Quest libraries thread-safe?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the quest library, as google turns up naught for it as well as "libvas.so.2".

Comment: You can use this reference for more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463156.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link to IBM's documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/gtpwnamr.htm), `getpwnam_r()` is threadsafe although I couldn't tell you whether it's implementation uses the Quest libraries.

Have you checked the core dump and are you sure that the problem is related to thread-safety on this function? You could try carefully stubbing out this function perhaps and run in a multi-threaded environment to check whether this is causing the issue.

Comment: I ran a simple utility which retrieves user ID of a user in multiple places in multiple threads and the minute there are concurrent requests to the Quest libraries, it dumps core. 
 
I did some research of my own and with the help of this reference : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463156.aspx . I'm pretty sure that getpwnam_r is thread safe as I called this api in an environment that doesn't use Quest authentication and it didn't dump core but it did in an enviroment with Quest VAS libraries for authentication. So, Now I'm kinda sure that Quest's VAS libraries aren't thread safe.